# Setting default UITextField value of 0 (Calculator)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I'm making an application and part of it has a sort of calculator functionality.

Users have 4 `UITextField`s to which they input numbers, all of which should be optional - but if they are left **empty**, it should act as if they have entered **"0"** into the field.
How do I go about setting this default value of 0?

It's currently set so that the initial value in the `UITextField` is 0, but this can be deleted by the user (rendering an error), and doesn't allow for placeholder text.

Comment: you can simply put condition like this, If textfield.text! == "" || textfield.text! == "0"{  its }else{//some values }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the default value of the textField to "0"

```
textField.text = "0"
```

Now you need to check if the user has changed the `textField` and if the change has resulted in an **empty** text field.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let textFieldString = textField.text, let range = Range(range, in: textFieldString) else {
        return false
    }
    let newString = textFieldString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if newString.isEmpty {
        textField.text = "0"
        return false
    } else if textField.text == "0" {
        textField.text = string
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post exactly this answer, letter for letter. . Great minds think alike!